# How to correctly calculate HMAC in Google Apps Script using hexadecimal key

Tags: php, google-apps-script, hmac

I am trying to use API which requires HMAC to authenticate.
I was able to generate and use correct key using PHP (using instructions from vendor), but now I need to do the same in Google Apps Script, but I failed...

The API key provided by vendor is **C77C96EEF6F6995B** with information that this is 8 byte hexadecimal.

Below is my working PHP script:

```
<?php
$klucz = chr(hexdec('C7')).chr(hexdec('7C')).chr(hexdec('96')).chr(hexdec('EE')).chr(hexdec('F6')).chr(hexdec('F6')).chr(hexdec('99')).chr(hexdec('5B'));
$url = "https://www.ifirma.pl/iapi/abonent/miesiacksiegowy.json";
$nazwaUsera = "WIJARAY978@NIEKIE.COM";
$nazwaKlucza = "abonent";
$hashWiadomosci = hash_hmac("sha1",$url.$nazwaUsera.$nazwaKlucza, $klucz);
echo $hashWiadomosci;
?>
```

It generates a hash: **9b5f9bb41ac30b9c55b10f3cecdd6e12e852f274**
which when I'm using it with postman calling the API is working fine.
Problem is when I'm trying to replicate that in Google apps script in similar way:

```
function bytesToHex(data) {
    return data.map(function(e) {
        var v = (e < 0 ? e + 256 : e).toString(16);
        return v.length == 1 ? "0" + v : v;
    }).join("");
}

function callNumbers() {
  var klucz = String.fromCharCode(parseInt("C7",16))+String.fromCharCode(parseInt("7C",16))+String.fromCharCode(parseInt("96",16))+String.fromCharCode(parseInt("EE",16))+String.fromCharCode(parseInt("F6",16))+String.fromCharCode(parseInt("F6",16))+String.fromCharCode(parseInt("99",16))+String.fromCharCode(parseInt("5B",16)); 

  var user = "WIJARAY978@NIEKIE.COM"
  var url = "https://www.ifirma.pl/iapi/abonent/miesiacksiegowy.json";
  var wiadomosc = url+user+"abonent";

  var hmac = Utilities.computeHmacSignature(Utilities.MacAlgorithm.HMAC_SHA_1, wiadomosc, klucz);
  
  hmac=bytesToHex(hmac)
  Logger.log(hmac);
}
```

This returns me completely different calculated hash: **6f50edae11b1f7f5b8488a99c4df3e797662c739**

Please help me to debug it.

btw. Credentials inside the code are working ones for dummy account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, how about converting the HEX values of `$klucz = chr(hexdec('C7')).chr(hexdec('7C')).chr(hexdec('96')).chr(hexdec('EE')).chr(hexdec('F6')).chr(hexdec('F6')).chr(hexdec('99')).chr(hexdec('5B'));` to the byte array in Google Apps Script? At Google Apps Script, I thought that to use the byte array might be suitable rather than the use of the binary data.

When this is reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

In this modification, the function `callNumbers()` is modified.

```js
function callNumbers() {
  var hex = "C77C96EEF6F6995B";
  var klucz = hex.match(/.{2}/g).map(e => parseInt(e[0], 16).toString(2).length == 4 ? parseInt(e, 16) - 256: parseInt(e, 16));

  var user = "WIJARAY978@NIEKIE.COM"
  var url = "https://www.ifirma.pl/iapi/abonent/miesiacksiegowy.json";
  var wiadomosc = url+user+"abonent";

  var hmac = Utilities.computeHmacSignature(Utilities.MacAlgorithm.HMAC_SHA_1, Utilities.newBlob(wiadomosc).getBytes(), klucz);
  
  hmac=bytesToHex(hmac)
  Logger.log(hmac);
}
```

- By converting the HEX value to the byte array, the arguments of `Utilities.computeHmacSignature` are also required to be converted to the byte array.
- When this script is run, `9b5f9bb41ac30b9c55b10f3cecdd6e12e852f274` is obtained. This is the same value with the value by your PHP script.
- Of course, `var klucz = ['C7', '7C', '96', 'EE', 'F6', 'F6', '99', '5B'].map(e => parseInt(e[0], 16).toString(2).length == 4 ? parseInt(e, 16) - 256 : parseInt(e, 16));` can be also used.

#### Reference:

- [computeHmacSignature(algorithm, value, key)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#computehmacsignaturealgorithm,-value,-key)

Comment: I'm curious about the hex to byte conversion, why when the length of the first binary equals 4 you subtract 256 from it? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Tcheslav Tcheslav Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: @Emel CD About your question of `why when the length of the first binary equals 4 you subtract 256 from it?`, because, at Google Apps Script, the bytes array of the signed hexadecimal is used.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I found this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement that explain the process